# Why count($_COOKIE) > 0 returns 'true' case while all cookies are deleted?

Tags: php, web, cookies

I am trying to delete a cookie by setting that cookie in past time:

```
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "david";
//subtraction from time causes deletion of cookie 
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() - (86400 * 30), "/");
```

With the below code I try to check whether cookie is enabled or not and it returns if case rather than else part, while I already dell that cookie:

```
//counting number of cookies
if(count($_COOKIE) > 0) {
    echo "<br>Cookies are enabled/exists";
} else {
    echo "<br>Cookies are disabled/not exists";
}
```

But the else part is not working when we delete cookie and I don't know why?

Comment: I think the definition *"Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE array."* from the [PHP manuals](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) means, that you access the cookies in the current page call, that were set in the last page call. So in order to make `setcookie()` be evaluated, you would need to reload the page. The statment *"When deleting a cookie you should assure that the expiration date is in the past, to trigger the removal mechanism in your browser"* also indicates, that the browser deletes the cookie, not the server.

Comment: what is the purpose of `time() - (86400 * 30)`

Comment: @devpro To set the cookie in the past, so it gets automatically removed by the browser, because it expired.

Comment: so you have issue in expiry time..

Comment: the issue is why count($_COOKIE) > 0 returns true case while i already delete that cookie it should be 0. is'nt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is you just set `user` cookie time to past date **not all the other cookie** in super global `$_COOKIE` array . Try like this way to set for all `$_COOKIE` value using `foreach()` to past date and then check `count` condition.

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "david";
$past_time = time() - 3600;
//use look set all cookie time to past date. 
foreach ( $_COOKIE as $key => $value )
{
    setcookie( $key, $value, $past_time, '/' );
}

//counting number of cookies
if(count($_COOKIE) > 0) {
    echo "<br>Cookies are enabled/exists";
} else {
    echo "<br>Cookies are disabled/not exists";
}

?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/jvRXW

Comment: i'll check it out

Comment: @MuhammadGulraiz I've tried already and added a demo for you. Let me know it is working or not for you ? you can see the `DEMO` now

Comment: @MuhammadGulraiz glad it work for you bro..by the way you can up vote it :)

Comment: Bro, I've already do that. But as a newbie, my vote is recorded but not shown.

Comment: @MuhammadGulraiz okkk bro.., best of luck :) happy coding